# Reset TCP KeepAlive Timer

Tags: c, linux, tcp

If on Linux, I set TCP_KEEPIDLE to a 3600 second interval. Then say I wait 3000 seconds, and reset the value from 3600 to 7200... Will the keep alive timer fire in 4200 seconds or 7200?

Answer (score 1):

the kernel takes the difference between the new keepalive timeout. if it's less than or equal to 0, it fires immediately, else it will fire at the difference.

aka in the given example, it will fire in 4200 seconds.

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/6bc3fe8e7e172d5584e529a04cf9eec946428768/net/ipv4/tcp.c#L2947